# Why XML method of SPLITing comma separated string taking way more time than conventional CURSOR or WHILE loop method of doing so

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

I have a table with 4 columns, one of which is a string with comma separated values. I used two approaches to slit and expand that list in the form of table:

I approach> Using XML:

```
declare @tbl TABLE (
    id1 int,
    id2 int,
    id3     int,
    str1        varchar(255)
    )

INSERT  INTO @tbl
SELECT p.n.value('@id1','INT'), p.n.value('@releaseId','INT'), p.n.value('@id3','INT'), '', p.n.value('.','nvarchar(150)')
FROM (SELECT CAST(('<r id1="'+CAST(id1 AS varchar(20))+'" id2="'+CAST(id2 AS varchar(20))+'" id3="'+CAST(id3 AS varchar(20))+'">'+REPLACE(CAST(str1 AS nvarchar(MAX)), ',', '</r><r id1="'+CAST(id1 AS varchar(20))+'" id2="'+CAST(id2 AS varchar(20))+'" id3="'+CAST(id3 AS varchar(20))+'">')+'</r>') AS XML) AS x 
    FROM SomeTable WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(str1 AS nvarchar(MAX)) <> '') R
CROSS APPLY R.x.nodes('/r') p(n)

select * from @tbl
```

II approach> Using CURSOR and WHILE LOOP method

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
        @sInputList VARCHAR(MAX) -- List of delimited items
      , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
    ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(100))

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
     BEGIN
     SELECT
      @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
      @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

     IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
      INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
     END

    IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
     INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
    RETURN
    END
    GO

-------------------------------------------
    DECLARE @id1    INT
    DECLARE @id2        INT
    DECLARE @id3        INT
    DECLARE @str1   nvarchar(MAX)

    declare @tbl TABLE (
            id1 int,
            id2 int,
            id3     int,
            str1        varchar(255)
            )

    DECLARE getList CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  Id1, Id2, Id3, str1
    FROM    someTable
    OPEN getaddUpdList
    FETCH NEXT FROM getList INTO @id1, @id2, @id3, @str1
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO @tbl
        SELECT  @id1, @id2, @id3, '', _ID
        FROM    fnSplit(@str1, ',')
        FETCH NEXT FROM getList INTO @id1, @id2, @id3, @sp, @str1
    END
    CLOSE getList
    DEALLOCATE getList

    select * from @tbl
```

As what I have read online, everywhere, CURSORS or WHILE loop should be avoided. But here in this case, when I try both of the above methods, the I approach is taking about 15-20 secs while the II approach is taking less than a sec. I couldn't understand why is it so. I have tried this on both SQL SERVER 2008 and 2012, but the results are same.

Any help in understanding such erratic behavior would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This question is long ago, but maybe you come around again. The simple point is, that you misunderstood the approach of splitting a string via XML. Look at this  example:

```
declare @tbl TABLE (
    id1 int,
    id2 int,
    id3     int,
    str1        varchar(255)
    )

INSERT  INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,2,3,'This,is,text,1')
,(10,20,30,'This,is,text,2')
,(100,200,300,'This,is,text,3')
,(1000,2000,3000,'This,is,text,4');


WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT id1 
          ,id2
          ,id3
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(str1,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS AsXml
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT id1,id2,id3
      ,The.Node.value('.','varchar(max)') AS splitvalue 
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY Casted.AsXml.nodes('/x') AS The(Node)
```

The trick is, to replace the delimmiter character(s) with an end and a start tag. The start tag at the beginning and the end tag at the end let the string be partial XML. The `CROSS APPLY` calls the `nodes()` function. The `value()`-function picks the value of the current (and in this case sole) node.